# Filter only get one condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a validation in WHERE clause like:

```
                         ...
                         AND (@BDOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsBDChecked)
                         AND (@CDOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsCDChecked)
                         AND (@PPOOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsPPOChecked)
                         AND (@FBOMOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsFBOMChecked)
                         AND (@APOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsAPChecked)
                         AND (@COOnly = 0
                             OR [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsCOChecked)
```

So each AND clause check if boolean is bit value is `0` or `1`, if it's `0` just do any but if it's `1` it do a filter. My problem is 
if I'm sending two with value `1`, I mean

`@BDOnly = 1` and `@CDOnly = 1` it only filter one of them instead get two filters I mean:

```
[DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsBDChecked
```

and

```
 [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsCDChecked
```

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: What is the value of `@IsBDChecked`, `@IsCDChecked` and `Abbreviation` of the record you think is not filtered correctly?

Comment: You'll find what you need [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: Its just a string,I think the problem is in  AND cluses because it filter only one of them, my desire result is to get  filter by string 1 and filter by string 2 so result should be  contain combination of two string values @MarcinJ

Comment: No you see if it's just a string, a string (Abbreviation) cannot equal two different strings (the two variables). That's why it's important you let us know what these values are, and might be, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here because there's not enough data. If you want to return a row where `Abbreviation` matched `@IsBDChecked` only when `@BDOnly` is set, and also another row where `Abbreviation` matches `@IsCDChecked` when `@CDOnly` is set, try this:

```
                        (@BDOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsBDChecked)
                     OR (@CDOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsCDChecked)
                     OR (@PPOOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsPPOChecked)
                     OR (@FBOMOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsFBOMChecked)
                     OR (@APOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsAPChecked)
                     OR (@COOnly = 1
                         AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @IsCOChecked)
```

Small representative case:

```
DECLARE @ADOnly BIT = 0
      , @BDOnly BIT = 1
      , @CDOnly BIT = 1
      , @IsADChecked NVARCHAR(100) = 'A'
      , @IsCDChecked NVARCHAR(100) = 'C'
      , @IsBDChecked NVARCHAR(100) = 'B'



;WITH myTable AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) X(Abbreviation)
)
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE (@ADOnly = 1 AND Abbreviation = @IsADChecked)
    OR (@BDOnly = 1 AND Abbreviation = @IsBDChecked)
    OR (@CDOnly = 1 AND Abbreviation = @IsCDChecked)
```

Yields:

```
Abbreviation
------------
B
C
```